# Showing N list items in React component without JQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After lots of reading on SO, I've come to the conclusion that using JQuery inside a React component is for the most part, bad practice. So how would I accomplish the following, being React-friendly as possible...

Lets say I have a list in my component:

```
let myList = [
    {title: 'list item 1'},
    {title: 'list item 2'},
    {title: 'list item 3'},
    {title: 'list item 4'},
    {title: 'list item 5'},
    {title: 'list item 6'}
]
```

I only want to show the first 3 items, unless `Show All` is clicked.

And my `render()` looks like:

```
render () {

    return (
      <div>
      myList.map(function(item, i) {
          <a>{item.title}</a>
      }
      <a>Show All</a>
      </div>
   )
}
```

I know how how to do this in JQuery, but I'm wondering what my solution would be using React best practices.

Comment: When you say you want to only show 3 items, what does that mean? The first 3? 3 that match a certain criteria?

Comment: First 3. I'll edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a function that encapsulates the logic of what to show. Then, you'll need to use state to capture whether Show All was clicked or not, so that you can differentiate when you want to show the first 3 and when you want to show all. The key is to return an array of the jsx you want rendered:

```
renderItems() {
  const itemList = [];
  // can be more succinct here - just for demo purposes
  for (let i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.showAll !== true && i === 3) {
      break;
    }
    itemList.push(<a>{ myList[i].title }</a>);
  }
  return itemList;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.renderItems() }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You'll then need to add a handler for when someone clicks "Show All" to set the state:

```
<a onClick={ this.showAll }>Show All</a>
```

If you reference a instance method like this, make sure you bind it in the constructor back to "this":

```
constructor() {
  this.showAll = this.showAll.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    showAll = false;
  };
}
showAll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ showAll: true });
}
```